# The `__init__.py` import multiple modules while they are not utilized within the file

Tags: django, design-patterns, facade

I am reading [`/django/forms/__init__.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/__init__.py)

```
"""
Django validation and HTML form handling.
"""

from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError  # NOQA
from django.forms.boundfield import *  # NOQA
from django.forms.fields import *  # NOQA
from django.forms.forms import *  # NOQA
from django.forms.formsets import *  # NOQA
from django.forms.models import *  # NOQA
from django.forms.widgets import *  # NOQA
```

The `__init__.py` import multiple modules while they are not utilized within the files.

I assume they might be employed by others lived in the same dir, How Django achieve this?

Comment: I'm not clear what your question is. These imports allow users to do imports like `from django.forms import Form` and `from django.forms import ModelForm` instead of `from django.forms.forms import Form` and `from django.forms.models import ModelForm`.

Comment: but, there're no codes after them in `__init__`. @Alasdair

Comment: Note the presence of # NOQA, this approach may "looks bad", Django understands and states: they're there for some reason. as @Alasdair explained in comment above

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot @Lemayzeur

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The `__init__.py` import multiple modules

s/modules/names/ - the `from somemodule import somename` syntax exposes the `somename` name, not `somemodule`.

> while they are not utilized within the files.
>   I assume they might be employed by others lived in the same dir

Actually this is a design pattern known as "facade" - the `forms` package hides it's inner implementation (in which submodule / subpackage is something defined) so

1/ the users can just import what they need from `django.forms` without having to care about the underlying modules / subpackages hierarchy,

and

2/ the mainainers can reorganize the underlying modules / subpackages hierarchy without breaking client code.

> How Django achieve this?

This is nothing Django specific, it's just plain ordinary Python. Read Python's doc about modules and packages.